# how to recognise a keyboard input in a string through java

Tags: java, string, jsp

I am trying to create a input box for a normal user who don't understand what HTML is, so i am trying to make few short codes like ## 'to center the text' or [[ 'to make it bold'. What i am thinking to implement this is to replace such special pre decided symbols with html code performing that particular task, this should be an easy task for a java expert, but as a newbie i am struggling a lot in doing this, i want to know how can i recognize occurrence of a keyboard character like ' { , [, : , ' etc ' in between text/string when providing input in a text box  using java/jsp, in my application, i have to recognise such inputs from key board in a text string and replace them with html code.Please help.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do.  Are you trying to escape them (turn & into `&amp;`)?  Are you trying to react whenever someone presses a key?

Comment: I had edited the question, hope you can help me now.

Comment: It's a lot clearer now.  Depending on what you need to do with that text, you might be able just to use EpicEditor:  http://oscargodson.github.com/EpicEditor/

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to replace those characters while the user is typing, you have to use `onKeyPressed` function (  `JavaScript`  ) to check every keyboard input and replace it with the desired html code.

Otherwise, you may have it transferred to your application and do the replacements there.